# Google Map partial Map Display on Jqm/Cordova/Android Page when revisiting the page

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to build a Jqm/Cordova/Android app with Google Map Support. I have used jQuery Map UI to show map using variable passed via a URL link in a listview. When I first visit the page it shows the map correctly but when I revisit the page It shows a part of the Map.

index.html > branch_locator.html (Showing a listview with 4 URL Parameters for map.html)

map.html : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr1F8.jpg

Revisited map.html : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjRx3.jpg

Here is Code Sample for map.html :

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="f" id="Gomap" style="width:100%; height:100%;">

<div role="banner" class="ui-bar-a ui-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-    toggle="false">
<a data-transition="slide" data-theme="f" href="branch_locator.html"  data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="arrow-l">
                      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">
                          Back
                        </span>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l ui-icon-shadow">
                        </span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                    <h1 aria-level="1" role="heading" tabindex="0" class="ui-title">
                      Google Map
                    </h1>

                </div>

                <div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;">

                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%;"></div>

                    Loading map....

                </div>

                <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="foot">

                  <h4>
                    Developed by Md. Thuhidul Islam Khan
                  </h4>

                </div>
                <!-- /footer -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>

</div>
```

CSS used for the map_canvas :

```
#map_canvas
{
position: absolute !important;
top: 40px !important;
bottom: 40px !important;
left:20px !important;
right:20px !important;
}
```

map.js code :

```
var latt1;

var longg1;

var latt2;

var longg2;

$("#Gomap").on("pageshow", function(e) {

var s = $(this).data("url");

var lat1Part = s.split("&")[0];

var long1Part = s.split("&")[1];

var lat2Part = s.split("&")[2];

var long2Part = s.split("&")[3];

latt1 = lat1Part.split("=")[1];

longg1 = long1Part.split("=")[1];

latt2 = lat2Part.split("=")[1];

longg2 = long2Part.split("=")[1];


});


loadScript();

function initialize() {


$('#map_canvas').empty();

var ur_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(latt1, longg1);

var br_pos = new google.maps.LatLng(latt2, longg2);

$('#map_canvas').gmap();
$('#map_canvas').gmap({
'center': ur_pos
});
$('#map_canvas').gmap({
'zoom': 6
});

$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
'position': br_pos,
'bounds': true,
'icon':'img/logo.png',
'animation': google.maps.Animation.DROP
}).click(function() {

$('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
'content': '<B>This is a AIBL Branch</B>'
}, this);

});

$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
'position': ur_pos,
'bounds': true,
'animation': google.maps.Animation.DROP
}).click(function() {

$('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
'content': '<B>Your Current Position</B>'
}, this);

});

$('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
}

function loadScript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Google Map Key&sensor=false&' +
'callback=initialize';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I need help to resolve the problem. For more code sample please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `loadScript();` inside the `$("#Gomap").on("pageshow", function(e) {});`

Comment: It works for me, but the map going under the footer part(you can see the SceenShot of map.html in my question part), can you help me on this matter? But thanx for the Answer.

Comment: I have solved the css problem by using below css on the div holing the map_canvas div .... 
   .map
    {
 position: absolute !important;
 top: 40px !important;
 bottom: 40px !important;
 left:20px !important;
 right:20px !important;
    }
Is it the right way..